# How to set unique IDs to a raster image?

Tags: r, raster

I am new to R. I want to set unique IDs for each pixel in a raster image (240 m resolution) and then disaggregate t0 30 m resolution.

I tried this code, but not working.

`    ndvi<-list.files(pattern = glob2rx("*ndvi*.tif$"), full.names=FALSE)

```
create_ids <-function(raster){
  df<-as.data.frame(raster, xy=TRUE)
  df<- df%>%

  mutate(ID = paste(x, y, sep="-")) %>%
 select(ID, layer)
  return(df)
}

disaggregate <-function(raster,res){
  cols <- ncol(raster) * (res(raster) / res)
  rows<-nrow(raster) * (res(raster)/res)

  grid<-expand.grid(x=1:cols, y-1:rows)
  df<-cbind(grid, raster::extract(raster, raster::xyFromCell(raster, grid), cells = TRUE))
  return (df)

}

output_res <-30


for (i in ndvi){
 r<-raster(i)
  #create IDs
  ids<-create_ids(r)
```

#write IDs to file
write.csv(ids, str_replace(file, ".tif", "_ids.csv"))

#Disaggregate
disagg <-disaggregfate_raster(r,30)

#Join IDs
disagg<-left_join(disagg, ids, by=c("layer"="ID"))

#write disaggregated raster
outfile<-str_replace(i, ".tif", "_disagg.tif")`your text`
writeRaster(disagg, outfile)
}

I want to do this for time series `

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the desired output using the `terra` package. In particular, the `subst` and `disagg` functions are the ones respondible for doing the key steps. Here is an example with a dummy raster.

```
library(terra)

# Create dummy raster in UTM 15 N
im <- rast(matrix(1:25000000, nrow = 5000, ncol = 5000),
     crs = "EPSG:32615")
# Aggregate values to get 240 m pixels
im <- aggregate(im, fact = 240)
# Check resolution
res(im)

# Substitute values with id values, 1 to xcells * ycells * zbands
im <- subst(im, 
            from = values(im), 
            to = seq(1,dim(im)[1] * dim(im)[2] * dim(im)[3], 1))
plot(im)

# Disaggregate to desired resolution ) 240 / 8 = 30
im2 <- disagg(im, fact = 8, method = "near")
# Check resolution
res(im2)
# Check values
values(im2)
# Plot
plot(im2)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried but it is not working for original raster images.                     
> ndvi<-list.files(pattern = glob2rx("*ndvi*.tif$"), full.names=FALSE)
> im<-stack(ndvi)
> # Substitute values with id values, 1 to xcells * ycells * zbands
> im <- subst(im, 
+             from = values(im), 
+             to = seq(1,dim(im)[1] * dim(im)[2] * dim(im)[3], 1))
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘subst’ for signature ‘"RasterStack"’

Comment: Try using the `terra` package instead of `raster`. `terra` is considered to be the replacement of `raster` package

Answer (score 0):

Example raster dataset

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(xmin=0, xmax=2400, ymin=0, ymax=2400, res=240)
```

Assign cell numbers

```
y <- init(x, "cell")

ncell(y)
#[1] 100
minmax(y)
#    lyr.1
#min     1
#max   100
```

Disaggregate

```
z <- disagg(y, 8)
res(r)
[1] 30 30
```

These are standard operations for which there are custom functions. See `?terra::terra and https://rspatial.org/spatial/index.html to get oriented.

Comment: I am trying to assign the unique values to the layer, but it is not saving. base=raster('base.tif')
values(base)=seq(ncell(base)) #assign unique values to the base layer
names(base)='pid'
writeRaster(base, 'base1.tif')

Comment: You should use `init`